# Using more than one *.Designer.cs (or view) per form

Tags: c#, winforms

I need to build a WinForms app that would have customized form/view layouts, depending on which device it's run on -- i.e. a small hand-held tablet, vs a larger tablet, vs a full monitor, as well as orientation -- landscape vs portrait.

What is the best way to approach this? Is there a way to have multiple *.Designer.cs files per *.cs file?

I'm aware of the various design patterns such as MVP as well. If that's the route to use in this case, what would be an example on how to switch between the various views seamlessly? Thanks.

Comment: A winform is supposed to be displayed in a typical windows OS
when moving to tablets or phones, the OS will not be exactly same
I am in doubt weather we can run a simple windows form application in mobile OS. But for adaptive layouts in winforms, check FlowLayoutPanel and TreeLayOutPanel from toolbox

Comment: The OS is Windows 7 or Windows 8. It's the hardware that has many different form-factors.